# Rails - Access file sitting in different port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, open-uri

I have two instances of web server. One is running on port 3000 and one is running on 9090. I want to access the JSON file sitting in the 9090 port.

In the rails model, I'm able to access the JSON file fine when I use

```
stream = open("http://localhost:9090/file.json")
```

But what I want to do is something more like

```
stream = open(":9090/file.json") # OUTPUT: No such file or directory - :9090/file.json
```

I want to avoid hardcoding the URL (obviously), and if I also want to avoid passing in the 'domain' from Rails controller to rails model.

Or is there a package that handles accessing different port, if openURI doesn't do this?

Thank you!

Comment: is there a way to add options to your `open` method? Something like `open("url", :port => 9090)`

Comment: I'm using Ruby's openURI, and it seems like not... http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html

Comment: Why don't you want to pass it from the controller? You could set it while initializing your model instance and store it in an instance variable for example ... I think it's clean enough

Comment: Intrepidd's solution seems good, but I'm starting to think that maybe I'll just pass in the variable from the controller...!

Comment: If your application can be accessed from several domains (for example one domain per country ...), it's easier to get it from the controller than setting it up in yaml

Comment: @AnthonyAlberto I decided to just pass it from the controller! I wish I can mark that as answer but I don't know since how I worded the question... Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a global CONFIG variable, that will load the content of config/config.yml for instance.

You can load this file in an initializer, here is mine :

```
if !defined? CONFIG
  CONFIG = YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, "config", "config.yml"))[Rails.env] rescue []
end
```

Then in your model :

```
stream = open("#{CONFIG['url']}:9090/file.json")
```

Assuming your config.yml looks like this :

```
development:
  url: http://localhost

production:
  url: http://what.ever
```